# What is Mysql select statement to show a list of tables?

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to write a program that can show the user a list of tables in the database and also show the descriptions of those tables.  So can I do a "select * from system_table" or something like that?

Answer (score 6):

This will give you a list of tables:

```
show tables;
```

To describe each table:

```
describe table_name;
```

To get both at the same time try:

```
SELECT * FROM DOMAIN.TABLES WHERE TYPE = 'TABLE'

SELECT * FROM DOMAIN.COLUMNS WHERE TABLETYPE = 'TABLE'
```

The results are similar to MySql show and describe statements

Comment: What is the domain and where would you find this information?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `show tables`, MySQL 5.0+ also supports the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` meta-database:

```
SELECT table_name, table_comment FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_schema = 'db_name';
```

[`information_schema.tables`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html) also has other information in it, if you're curious.

Note that if you didn't provide a comment when you created the table and use InnoDB, it will fill the table_comment column with unnecessary data, such as the InnoDB space reserved for this table or the foreign key constraints.

Comment: I am running an older version of mysql 4.1x so this will not work for me, but thank you for the suggestion.